# Unknown attribute android:scaleType

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

[image]

This is the error. As shown in the image. This is not letting the app run.
This happens when I set the compile sdk version to 33. What to do?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either ignore it or upgrade to Android Studio - Dolphin; it is a known bug. I had literally hundreds of these `Unknown Attribute` errors in my project, but they went away when I upgraded to Dolphin v2021.3.1.

Here's a link to Google's issue tracker indicating it is resolved in Dolphin: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241460885